# Kraken API unknow method

Tags: python, api

```
def public_req(api_method):
    URL = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/'
    url = URL + api_method
    r = requests.get(url + api_method)
    return r.json()


def main():
    print(public_req('Assets'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

На печать выходит {'error': ['EGeneral:Unknown method']}. Подскажите что не так. https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-asset-info ссылка на апи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насчет API, но в коде у вас путаница, думаю, должно быть так:

```
URL = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/'
url = URL + api_method
r = requests.get(url)
```

А то, у вас получалась такая URL - `https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetsAssets`

Comment: Мда, запарился. Спасибо!

Comment: @VitalyTolokonnikov, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)